# How to auto empty table on specified time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to remove all records in my table when time is 23.59, I have the  following query:

```
function delChat() {
    $date = date('H:i');
    $this->db->where(dimasukkan, '23:59');
    $this->db->delete('chat');
}
```

but nothing happens

Comment: how time is saved in table?

Comment: Your `where()` statement is wrong, it needs to be `where('column', $value)` and you will need a cron/task  to do this.

Comment: [Cron Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Do you need automitacally remove records when time is 23:59, or you need manually execute query and delete records where time from `your_date_column = '23:59'` ?

Comment: Thanks guys for the replays, Kisaragi my bad, I just changed the Where section, and Oto I need auto delete when time is 23.59 everyday.

Comment: Is Cron the only way to make an auto delete like this? Thanks

Comment: you are referring to truncate I suppose... delete is to fully remove the table. Truncate deletes only the record inside but keep the table

Comment: @LelioFaieta - `delete` also keep the table. it is `DROP` command, which fully removes the table

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that I don't know PHP, so I can't provide working code. However, I'll try to help out.

First, your question is ambiguous. Do you mean that you want to remove all records from the table every day when it is 23:59 h, or do you mean that you must remove every record whose timestamp is 23:59 h?

**If you want to empty the table every day when it is 23:59 h,** a `cron` job would be the right thing (as some comments already propose).

The `cron` job could be used on Linux / Unix systems; an alternative to that would be `at`. Under Windows, you could use the *task scheduler* for regularly running your job.

In every case, please be aware that you actually can't predict how long the operation will take. Possibly it will still run when it is already 00:00 h, or even 00:01 h the next day, which will eventually get you into trouble.

**If you want to delete every row whose *timestamp* or `date` column is 23:59 h,** your code has some problems:

- Your `where` statement is wrong. You are comparing a normal variable to a constant here. I have no clue what PHP / MySQL are doing in such cases, but it certainly is not what you expect. If you want to compare e.g. a `date` column to that constant, you would have to it that way: `... where('date', '23:59')`.
- Almost certainly, your `date` column or timestamp does not contain the date / time in the format needed. Hence, if you want to compare `hour:minute` to your `date` or timestamp column, you would first have to extract the hour and the minute from it and concatenate that to the format needed (or perhaps MySQL already provides an appropriate function for that), and then compare the result to your string constant.